# What is the reason of overlapping instances error?

Tags: haskell

What is the reason of error "Overlapping instances for ToJSON [XYZ]" in this example:

```hs
data XYZ = XYZ Int
instance ToJSON [XYZ] where
  toJSON xs = ...
```

and GHC shows as overlapping instance this:

```
instance ToJSON a => ToJSON [a] ...
```

which is not a suitable case: `XYZ` has not `ToJSON` instance yet. I can fix it with `{-# OVERLAPS #-}` but I don't understand why GHC does not understand that `[a]` where `a` has not `ToJSON` needs explicit definition for `ToJSON`. What do I miss?

Comment: *XYZ has not ToJSON instance yet*

It doesn't matter. Constraints like `ToJSON a =>` are not considered when checking for overlapping instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `XYZ` has not `ToJSON` instance yet

you say it yourself – no instance **yet**. There is no way to be sure somebody doesn't add that instance later on. What's supposed to happen in this case? In particular, if one piece of code doesn't see the instance yet and therefore picks `instance ToJSON a => ToJSON [a]`, and another piece later on *has* the instance in scope, you'd get two possibly incompatible instances being in use simultaneously. Havoc.

I reckon you probably want to express `instance ToJSON XYZ` should *never* be defined, but really Haskell has no notion of a type being *not* an instance of a class. The assumption is that every type is *potentially* an instance of every class – only perhaps it's not possible to *see* the instance yet.

Ok, actually it *is* possible to disable an instance from being really defined – by defining it yourself, with an [unfulfillable superclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.11/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Bottom):

```
instance Bottom => ToJSON XYZ where
  toJSON = no
```

...which will cause a type error if you try to invoke `toJSON` for `XYZ` anywhere. But still, as far as the language is concerned this *is* an instance, it just happens to be a “un-typecheckeable instance”.

So, the instances *are* overlapping, even if the overlap may not actually be something that could compile – but the instance resolution doesn't attempt to check that, i.e. to *try* compile it, that would get extremely inefficient quickly and in general lead to quite unpredictable program behaviour. (If you've ever worked with advanced C++ templates, you know what I mean.)

Instead, instance lookup always just matches the *instance head*, i.e. `[a]` vs. `[XYZ]`. Which, now clearly, do overlap.

The proper thing to do for your application is probably to make a

```
newtype XYZs = XYZs { getXYZs :: [XYZ] }

instance ToJSON XYZs where
  ...
```

If you find that syntactically awkward, note you can use the `OverloadedLists` extension

```
import GHC.Exts (IsList(..))

instance IsList XYZs where
  type Item XYZs = XYZ
  fromList = XYZs
  toList = getXYZs
```

and then

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
test :: XYZs
test = [XYZ 1, XYZ 2]
```

is legal.